# React typeError: this.state is null

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I'm creating a Contact Manager App, and I can Add and delete Contacts but I'm yet to Add an Edit Functionality and I've tried  to build an Edit Component to be able to edit my contacts, but when i run the Edit component i get an error saying "this.state is null" and this is pointing to the Edit Component...
This is what my Edit Component looks like;

```
class EditContact  extends Component {  
    changeFirstName = (event) => {
        const { contact } = this.state;
         const newContact ={
            ...contact,
            firstName: event.target.value
        };
        this.setState({ contact: newContact });
    }
    changeLastName = (event) => {
        const { contact } = this.state;
        const newContact ={
            ...contact,
            lastName: event.target.value
        };
        this.setState({ contact: newContact });
    }
    changeEmail = (event) => {
        const { contact } = this.state;
        const newContact ={
            ...contact,
            email: event.target.value
        };
        this.setState({ contact: newContact });
    }
    changePhone = (event) => {
        const { contact } = this.state;
        const newContact ={
            ...contact,
            phone: event.target.value
        };
        this.setState({ contact: newContact });
    }
    changeBalance = (event) => {
        const { contact } = this.state;
        const newContact ={
            ...contact,
            balance: event.target.value
        };
        this.setState({ contact: newContact });
    }
    render() {
        return  (
          <>
            <Navbar />
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-link">
                                <i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>Back To Contacts
                            </Link>
                            <br></br>
                            <p>
                                Need to Edit a few things about your Contacts, Go ahead and make all those changes here...!!!
                            </p>
                            <input
                             type="text"
                              onChange={this.changeFirstName}
                              value={this.state.contact.firstName} 
                            />
                            <input
                             type="text"
                              onChange={this.changeLastName}
                               value={this.state.contact.lastName}
                            />
                            <input
                             type="text"
                              onChange={this.changeEmail}
                               value={this.state.contact.email}
                            />
                            <input
                             type="text"
                              onChange={this.changePhone}
                               value={this.state.contact.phone}
                            />
                            <input
                             type="text"
                              onChange={this.changeBalance}
                               value={this.state.contactbalance}
                            />
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
           </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't initiate the state in the `constructor`

Answer (score 3):

You need to initiate the state in the constructor of the class:

```
class EditContact  extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) <== Not needed in latest react
    this.state = {
      contact: {},
      ...other
    }
  }

  // Rest of your component
```